# Simple scene splits up selecting collection in Sun Position

Tags: add-on, lighting

I think this is a bonehead Blender workflow fail on the user side. Blender 3.2 on Win10.

I've created a very simple model of two houses in Blender with the hopes of being able to do some simple shadow projection forecasting using [Sun Position](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/lighting/sun_position.html) (an add-on when enabled it appears in the World panel). I have the objects arranged in a collection, when I select the collection in the sun position panel, the scene 'blows up' in the viewport, with all the objects scattered vertically.

I tried setting child parent relationships, and I've tried locking the position of the parent object. I'm missing something silly I think (locking position to the origin, etc.). Any advice greatly appreciated.

Before sun-position
[image: Before sun-position]

After sun-position
[image: after sun-position]

Comment: *"when I select the collection in the sun position panel, ..."* - how and where do you do this?

Comment: Sun position is an add on, when enabled, appears in the World panel: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/lighting/sun_position.html

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that add-on. Nice one. After playing around with it a bit I wonder why you put the houses in the sun's visualization collection. I don't think this is what you want. The *Use Object* setting defines the *Sun* light object. And the *Use Collection* is to visualize the sun in the render. For example a sphere.

Comment: Hey, that advice was exactly what I needed and I now have it working. Thanks a million!